# Use of undefined constant icontext - assumed 'icontext'

Tags: php, mysqli

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require ("bd.php");

if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {   
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM ymapapiv2_markers_cat");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while ($mar = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $json =  array(icontext=>$mar['iconText'], hinttext=>$mar['hintText'], balloontext=>$mar['balloonText'], styleplacemark=>$mar['stylePlacemark'], lat=>$mar['lat'], lon=>$mar['lon']);
            markers[] = $json;
        }      
    }
    $points = array(markers=>$markers);
    echo json_encode($points);  
}
```

I get this error, what can I do?

> :41.343721 2017] [:error] [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:50094] PHP
>   Notice: Use tant icontext - assumed ’icontext’ in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch 1ist.local
>
> :41.343738 2017] [:error] [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:500941 PHP
>   Notice: Unde rext in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch 1ist.local
>
> :41.343746 20171 [:error! [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:500941 PHP
>   Notice: Use tant hinttext - assumed 'hinttext’ in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch 1ist.local
>
> :41.343753 20171 [:error! [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:500941 PHP
>   Notice: Use tant balloontext - assumed 'balloontext' in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch 1ist.local
>
> :41.343760 20171 [:error! [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:500941 PHP
>   Notice: Use tant styleplacemark - assumed ’styleplacemark' in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch 1ist.local
>
> :41.343767 20171 [:error! [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:500941 PHP
>   Notice: Unde ;Placemark in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch1ist.local
>
> :41.343775 20171 [:error! [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:500941 PHP
>   Notice: Use tant lat - assumed 'lat’ in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch1ist.local
>
> :41.343783 20171 [:error! [pid 1850] [client 192.168.137.1:500941 PHP
>   Notice: Use tant Ion - assumed 'Ion' in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/php/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 13, referer: watch1ist.local
>
> :41.343794 20171 [:error! [pid 18501 [client 192.168.137.1:50094! PHP
>   Notice: Use tant markers - assumed 'markers’ in
>   /home/coder/samba/public_htm1/watch1ist.loca1/vivodpointsmap-cat.php
>   on line 19, referer: watch1ist.local

Comment: Comment is needed to grasp the context. Please update.

Comment: What changes have you tried to make to your code? Does it make any difference? Can you show the same thing removing the items that are shown as errors? Then add them in one at a time to see where the problem really lies? What is `icontext` in your code? I don't see it defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not enclosing the keys for `$json` in `"` quotations. It should be like this:

```
$json =  array('icontext'=>$mar['iconText'], 'hinttext'=>$mar['hintText'], 'balloontext'=>$mar['balloonText'], 'styleplacemark'=>$mar['stylePlacemark'], 'lat'=>$mar['lat'], 'lon'=>$mar['lon']);
```

Comment: `[Thu Nou 23 04:28:15.343836 2017] [:error] [pid 1851] [client 192.168.137.1:50177] PHP Notice: Unde fined index: stylePlacemark in /home/coder/samba/public_html/watchlist.local/php/uiuodpointsmap-cat. php on line 13, referer: watchlist.local`

Comment: @OriginalBacer That only means that `$mar` array does not have value for `stylePlacemark`.